# convert dataframe to nested json

Tags: python, pandas

I am using

```
pd.read_sql_query()
```

to get data from database and then use

```
to_json(orient='records')
```

this is the dataframe:

```
(1)
  price_formula_id  premium  product_id  exchange  product_name  product_code   weight  
0            30064      0.0        c001       CME          2018            CL      0.3
1            30064      0.0        c002       CME          2018            CL      0.7

(2)
price_formula_id  premium  product_id  exchange  product_name  product_code   weight  
0            30064      NONE        c001       CME          2018            CL      0.3
1            30064      NONE        c002       CME          2018            CL      0.7
```

to convert to this formation.

```
[{
    "price_formula_id": "30064",
    "premium": "0.0",
    "product_id": "c001",
    "exchange": "CME",
    "product_name": "2018",
    "product_code": "CL",
    "weight": "0.3"
},
{
    "price_formula_id": "30064",
    "premium": "0.0",
    "product_id": "c002",
    "exchange": "CME",
    "product_name": "2018",
    "product_code": "CL",
    "weight": "0.7"
}]
```

but what I really want should be like this :

```
 { 
   "price_formula_id": "30064",
   "premium": "0.0",
   "basket": 
    [
     {"product_id": "c001",
      "exchange": "CME",
      "product_name": "2018",
      "product_code": "CL",
      "weight": "0.3"
     },
     {
      "product_id": "c002",
      "exchange": "CME",
      "product_name": "2018",
      "product_code": "CL",
      "weight": "0.7"
     }
    ]
 }
```

I need to group the same info and set a new index 'basket' for the rest.
how could I make it?
Thanks very much.

Comment: post your dataframe too

Comment: hi, just added it.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for all columns filtered by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last convert it [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['price_formula_id','premium'])
j = (df.groupby(['price_formula_id','premium'])[cols]
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='basket')
       .to_json(orient='records'))
print (j)

[{
    "price_formula_id": 30064,
    "premium": 0.0,
    "basket": [{
            "exchange": "CME",
            "product_code": "CL",
            "product_id": "c001",
            "product_name": 2018,
            "weight": 0.3
        },
        {
            "exchange": "CME",
            "product_code": "CL",
            "product_id": "c002",
            "product_name": 2018,
            "weight": 0.7
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: hi, thx for ur comment. but I got a error for this method said: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'. I check the declaration of reset_index() and this no params for it, how should I change it? thx

Comment: @Alex - You can try `.reset_index(name='basket')` change to `.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'basket'})`, change value for rename if necessary

Comment: one more thing need to ask what's function of ' r ' ? thx @jezrael

Comment: It is `records` like `orient='records'`

Comment: it works, thx. but when i got set a column as null(like 'premium': ' '), it will return [ ], I cant figure out why

Comment: @Alex - Can you change sample data?

Comment: yea, plz go check the dataframe sample (2) in the top

Comment: @Alex - Maybe help first step convert missing values to `null` string like `df = df.fillna('null')`