# Pandas forward fill proportionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Month/Year  Value  
01/2018     100  
03/2018     200  
06/2018     800
```

The values for 02/2018, 04/2018 and 05/2018 is missing because the value did not change in those months. I would like to have a dataframe which incudes the missing months and values are increased proportionally:

```
Month/Year  Value    
01/2018     100  
02/2018     150  
03/2018     200   
04/2018     400  
04/2018     600  
06/2018     800
```

Thank you for help with the solution!

Comment: what did you mean by value did not change? Are you comparing such month's value with any previous dataframe or something, also how did you determine the value of 02/2018 was 150?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolation on DataFrame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464738/interpolation-on-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column to `DatetimeIndex`, add missing datetimes by [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) and if necessary same format add [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Month/Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month/Year'], format='%m/%Y')
df = df.set_index('Month/Year').asfreq('MS').interpolate().reset_index()
df['Month/Year'] = df['Month/Year'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')
print (df)
  Month/Year  Value
0    01/2018  100.0
1    02/2018  150.0
2    03/2018  200.0
3    04/2018  400.0
4    05/2018  600.0
5    06/2018  800.0
```

Comment: hi @jezrael, can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530653/convert-dataframe-to-nested-json?noredirect=1#comment90029975_51530653

Comment: we can `interpolate` only on index?

Comment: @pyd - no, but it is necessary for `asfreq`

Comment: Can you check the above question once